# Seeking up to date Italian administrative boundaries?

Tags: data, italy

I am after Italian GIS data - administrative boundaries such as:

Regions (Regioni)
Provincies (Provincie)
Municipalities (Comuni)
Districts (Quartieri)
City quarters (Contrade o Rioni)
Zones (Zone)​​
Suburbs (Frazioni)

and Postcodes.

I can find data some data to download - for example
http://www.dati.gov.it/catalog/dataset

http://www.igmi.org/download.php

But I want to make sure I have the most up to date data.

Who is the official supplier of this data?
Which government department manages this GIS data?
When the data is updated how will I know?

In Australia  there is a government department that manages this data and every 3 months we are are sent updates if we pay some $.
I am not sure if there is an equivalent in Italy

Comment: Perhaps you could contact the Italian Geoportal ( http://www.pcn.minambiente.it/GN/progetto_pcn.php?lan=en). As their mission is most likely to gather datasets from the most reliable sources they might be able to point you in the right direction. Or you might even find the datasets you need readily available.

Answer (score 2):

Down to "comuni" level you can download SHAPE files from http://www.istat.it/it/archivio/104317

The available years are: 1991, 2001 and 2011. I didn't find an indication when to expect the next update.

Related data link: http://www.istat.it/it/strumenti/territorio-e-cartografia