# Seeking administrative divisions shapefile for Italy?

Tags: shapefile, data, italy

I am looking for administrative divisions' shapefile for Italy for QGIS. I found one which is a bit old with some inconsistencies.

Can anyone please suggest a database to find better (or newer) shapefiles?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Arbo94! Perhaps this post might help: [Where to get up to date Italian administrative boundaries?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132671/where-to-get-up-to-date-italian-administrative-boundaries) or you can try downloading some administrative shapefiles from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) =)

Comment: [This question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177741/looking-for-a-free-shapefile-of-the-european-countries) should also provide you with some additional resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all! I had used all these websites before I wrote here. The thing is that Italy has changed its administrative boundaries in 2016, and there is not a (free?!) shapefile map in the internet of the new boundaries.

Comment: ISTAT releases official data every year http://www.istat.it/it/archivio/124086

Answer (score 3):

You may download the data using the "WFS Services" of the National Geoportal, following this link:

[Catalog Service WFS - The National Geoportal](http://www.pcn.minambiente.it/GN/en/accesso-ai-servizi-eng/servizi-di-download-eng/wfs-eng)

and using the URL from "Unita' amministrative regionali, provinciali e comunali".

Comment: As of 2022, it's this link https://www.istat.it/it/archivio/222527

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look at the [GADM database](http://gadm.org/country), but sometimes shapefiles have inaccuracies too

Comment: Thank you but this was the shapefile that I sad has some discrepancies :D

Answer (score 2):

here is the work done by Franco Morelli
http://www.opendatabassaromagna.it/2016/12/i-confini-dei-comuni-italiani-al.html